# Just like the BeautifulSoup example...what's wrong?

Tags: python

So I am trying to scrape this vocabulary table using beautifulsoup:

http://www.homeplate.kr/korean-baseball-vocabulary

I tried to scrape it just as I did this table of football teams:

http://www.bcsfootball.org/

The first case:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.homeplate.kr/korean-baseball-vocabulary'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

for row in soup('table',{'class': 'tableizer-table'}):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

This outputs only one line of the table.

The second case:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.bcsfootball.org').read())

for row in soup('table',{'class': 'mod-data'})[0].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print tds[0].string, tds[1].string
```

This outputs the rank and school name for all 25 schools.

What am I doing wrong between the two examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one of them has `...[0].tbody('tr')`.

In the first code snippet, you're iterating over *tables* (despite your variable name of `row`), of which there is (presumably) only one.